# Is there any possible way to use mod_wsgi on localhost?

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi

I am a beginner of mod_wsgi. I just want to develop basic handler application to Apache. Here is my simple test.wsgi code. Apache localhost calls this wsgi first.

```
def application(environ,start_response):

 if (environ["PATH_INFO"]=="/"):

  start_response('200 OK', [])

  return ['It works'] 

 else:

  path = environ["SERVER_NAME"] + environ["PATH_INFO"] 

  start_response("303 See Other", [('location', path)]) 

  return [path]
```

But the main problem is localhost redirects too many times. Please help me to solve this problem? Is there any possible way? I want to develop simple handler application which analyzes `environ[query_string]`.

Many thanks,
Zoloo

Answer (score 0):

Read:

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#url-reconstruction

for the correct way to go about reconstructing the URL for use in redirects etc.

Better still, go use a micro framework like Flask. If you are new to this stuff trying to use WSGI at its most basic level is a bad idea. Use a system which does all this stuff for you properly.